# What is the physical interpretation of the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Some propositions in math can be modeled as a physical system. Has anyone done this for RH?

Comment: The RH, in its original form, has little to do with Riemannian geometry. It is a statement that principally belongs to number theory, with far-reaching generalizations that have implications in many other branches of mathematics (including geometry). At any rate, I vote to close, because it is unclear to me what you are asking. (Of course, the RH was considered by many physicists, including attempts to prove it.)

Comment: Here is one recent attempt at connection: "The Riemann Hypothesis and Emergent Phase Space," *Journal of Modern Physics*, Vol.08 No.04(2017): "By interpreting multifractal L-function zero alignment as a decoherence process, the Riemann hypothesis is demonstrated to imply the emergence of classical phase space at zero alignment."

Comment: Given the chronic, endemic tendency of some physicists to feel that they have an intuition for why RH should hold, even if they are technically naive in several different ways, I think this is a worthwhile question. Among other things, it starts to illustrate why the naive notion of "self-adjoint operator", that did not cause Dirac or others any trouble, cannot be naively extrapolated to situations without a guaranteed physical sense. Such things are mathematically interesting, I think.

Comment: @paulgarrett Based on the tag chosen by the OP, together with a quick look at their profile, I am not confident that an answer explaining these subtleties is what the OP is after. I would prefer to see a better question asked before people start trying to contribute scattershot answers

Comment: @YemonChoi, you're probably right, but I try to make the best of each situation... :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try '[Inxeplicable Secrets of Creation](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/isoc/)' by Matthew Watkins.

Answer (score 5):

See a lot of different ideas in the [paper by Schumayer and Hutchinson.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3116)